# How to keep track of values which are present in a group as well as in all previous group in oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have a table with col1 and col2
I group by col1 and order by col1

From the first group, I want to have all values of col2 but from the second group, I want to have only those values which were present in the first group and so on with the consecutive groups.

sample table

```
col1 col2
1     A
1     B
1     C
1     D
2     E
2     A
2     B
2     G
3     B
3     D
```

And the output should be

```
col1 col2

1     A
1     B
1     C
1     D
2     A
2     B
3     B
```

Comment: Hi. Please read [ask].  Can you edit the question and show sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions in order to avoid to read the same table twice:

1. Number the groups to make sure to have 1, 2, 3, ... without gaps.
2. Get a rolling count of col2, or in other words the cumulated numbers of their appearances.
3. Only show rows where the group number equals the count.

The query:

```
select col1, col2
from
(
  select
    col1, col2,
    dense_rank() over (order by col1) as rn,
    count(*) over (partition by col2 order by col1) as cnt
  from mytable
) numbered_and_counted
where rn = cnt
order by col1, col2;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f0cc6a211a1a4c767c9e3ce9deb8c28f

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and need to ask does it work with duplicates, it seems not but I have not verified with duplicates.
I believe this line "count(*) over (partition by col2 order by col1) " counts row where col2 present but if there are 2 same values in col2 it will count them and go out of sync with rn. Anyways I will try to use distinct rows from cte and then use this query on it.

Comment: @AmanSinghRajpoot . . . You might want to ask another question regarding duplicates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No thanks,  I just wanted to understand the logic. :)